# How to send all the details of customers to admin and few details of customers to vendor in new order email

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce

I am using following WooCommerce function to send customer details in an email to **admin** and **vendor** when the new order is created.

```
<?php 
/**
* WooCommerce new order email customer details
*/
function filter__woocommerce_email_customer_details_fields( $fields, $sent_to_admin, $order ) {

    if ( empty( $fields ) ) {

        if ( $order->get_billing_email() ) {
            $fields['billing_email'] = array(
            'label' => __( 'Email address', 'woocommerce' ),
            'value' => wptexturize( $order->get_billing_email() ),
            );
        }
        if ( $order->get_billing_phone() ) {
            $fields['billing_phone'] = array(
            'label' => __( 'Phone', 'woocommerce' ),
            'value' => wptexturize( $order->get_billing_phone() ),
            );
        }
        if ( $order->get_customer_note() ) {
            $fields['customer_note'] = array(
            'label' => __( 'Customer note', 'woocommerce' ),
            'value' => wptexturize( $order->get_customer_note() ),
            );
        }

    }

    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details_fields', 'filter__woocommerce_email_customer_details_fields', 10, 3 );
```

But now I want customization like when a new order email is sent to admin then all 3 details ( Email, Telephone and Notes ) need to send to admin , But only 2 details ( Emai and Notes ) need to send to Vendor

I am using **YITH WooCommerce Multi Vendor plugin** which sends order email to a particular vendor

How do I check that if an email is sent to admin then send all 3 details and if an email is sent to the vendor then send only 2 details ?

Answer (score 0):

Phone field should be sent to admin only and other fields to all. Your have to add condition to `if` construction for this. (I think `$sent_to_admin` is boolean value described should current message be sent to admin).

```
if ( $order->get_billing_phone() && $sent_to_admin ) {
    $fields['billing_phone'] = array(
        'label' => __( 'Phone', 'woocommerce' ),
        'value' => wptexturize( $order->get_billing_phone() ),
    );
}
```

Comment: @7uc1f3r Thank you for this , but I wan you to know that `$sent_to_admin` parameter is not intended to work field wise.

`$sent_to_admin` parameter checks that you want to send an entire email to admin or not

if  `$sent_to_admin` returns 1 that means the entire email  will be sent to admin
if  `$sent_to_admin` returns 0 that means the entire email  will not be sent to admin

Comment: @ParthaviPatel If `$sent_to_admin` is false, the mail is still being sent, but not to the admin. Why then shouldn't this be used as a condition? The condition will never be met as long as the mail is not addressed to the admin, and for that reason the field will not be added. I do not use that plugin but when I test this to admin and customer, the condition is only executed for the admin. Or am I missing something obvious here? You confuse me - According to your logic, the else condition in [my attached example](https://pasteboard.co/JiJFiHF.jpg) could never be executed, although it is

Comment: @7uc1f3r  Check my querstion , I have already mention that " all 3 details ( Email, Telephone and Notes ) need to send to admin " and " only 2 details ( Emai and Notes ) need to send to Vendor "

Using this variable `$sent_to_admin` ,  how do I differentiate whether an email is being to sent to Admin or Vendor ?

Comment: `$sent_to_admin` = 1, email being sent to admin, `$sent_to_admin` = 0, email NOT being sent to admin. But that contains all the other mails, and not specifically those to the vendor, so now I understand what you mean.

Comment: @7uc1f3r Yes, and I finally found the solution in this link , I have made some customization in the function mentioned in this link and fix this issue... https://support.yithemes.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000310568--How-to-hide-email-and-phone-number-of-the-customer-in-the-new-order-email-vendor

I